Show that $a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0$ is $\Omega(x^n)$
Suppose that $a_0, a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n $ are real numbers and $a_n \ne 0$. Show that $a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0$ is $\Omega(x^n)$ by letting
$$ d = 2 \Bigg( \frac{|a_0| + |a_1| + |a_2| + \cdots + |a_{n-1}|}{|a_n|} \Bigg) $$
and letting $a = \max(d, 1)$.
This means that I have to prove that there exist a positive real number $A$ and a nonnegative real number $a$ such that
$$ A\; |x^n| \leq \left| a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0 \right| \qquad \forall x > a$$
Now, when $x > 1$, I can deduce that $1 < x < x^2 < \cdots < x^n$. But I can't think of using triangle inequality here. I tried to manipulate $d$ but don't go anywhere.

Use the triangle inequality in a form such as $|p+q+r+s|\geq |p|-|q|-|r|-|s|$

I tried using that. If $f(x) = a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0$, then I was able to arrive at with the assumption that $x > 1$
$$ |x^n| \left( |a_n| - |a_{n-1}| - \cdots - |a_1| - |a_0| \right) \leq |f(x)| $$
How do I improve upon this ?

For large $x$ the value of $x^{n-1}$ is not just smaller than $x^n$ but it is smaller as many times as you wish. Or, if you first factor out $x^n$ then $a_i/x^i$, $i<n$, is as small as you wish.
